# How do I create a number field that displays the number with a specific number of characters using leading zeros?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, hooks

In Drupal 7, I would like to create a serial number for one of my content type displays. I could use a serial field or integer field that will auto increment the integer with module code or with rules. I would like this serial number to have a specific number of digits with leading zeros, four for instance.

Comment: Any issue using the NID and filling in leading with 0’s as needed?

Comment: As long as the NIDs didn't grow to a larger number of characters than required for the specific content type. Because NIDs are shared between all nodes, other content could create an issue. I want to keep the number of characters down to four so they can easily be communicated.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. A field that’s autoincremented sounds like a good idea then.